# Map on Javascript object values without extra variable?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm using the following piece of code (which is working fine)

```
  const result = {}
  Object.keys(timers).forEach(key => {
    result[key] = hydrate(timers[key])
  })
  return result
}
```

I'm wondering if this is possible in one method? So without having to fill the result object?

Comment: You are missing some code becuase `return result` should be inside another function.

Comment: You are reinventing reduce()

Comment: @epascarello That's what my question is about.. Kindly make an answer.

Comment: Follow the example? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce

Comment: You say “without having to fill the result object”, but why do you have to do this?

Answer (score 3):

Convert to entries with [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries), iterate the entries with [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and hydrate the values, and convert back to an object with [`Object.fromEntries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries):

```
const fn = timers => Object.fromEntries(
  Object.entries(timers).map(([k, v]) => [k, hydrate(v)])
)
```

Comment: Note for readers: `fromEntries` is ECMAScript 2019 and is not supported in all browsers/engines as of this writing (see the support grid at the bottom of the linked doc).

Comment: It actually has pretty decent support now days (all except IE/Edge/Opera), and it's easy to polyfill.

Answer (score 1):

Just use reduce

```js
var timers = {
  a: 2,
  b: 3,
  c: 4
}
 
const hydrate = x => 2*x

var result = Object.entries(timers).reduce((o, [key, value]) => {
  o[key] = hydrate(value)
  return o
}, {})

console.log(result)
```

without fat arrow

```js
var timers = {
  a: 2,
  b: 3,
  c: 4
}
 
function hydrate (x) { return 2 * x }

var result = Object.entries(timers).reduce(function(o, entry) {
  o[entry[0]] = hydrate(entry[1])
  return o
}, {})

console.log(result)
```